# Cannot execute a custom xpath rule on XML

Tags: xpath, sonarqube

I am trying to create custom XML rules but they are not working. :(

First my configuration :

- sonarqube 4.3
- xml plugin 1.2

I want to create a custom rule in xpath for an XML Quality Profile.
The rule is never applied and no violation is detected.

My rule :

```
//ELEMENT/S_TAG/NAME[@tokenValue='root']
```

My XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"  ?>
<root>          
</root>
```

The AST tree :

```
<DOCUMENT tokenValue="<?xml" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="0">
  <PROLOG tokenValue="<?xml" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="0">
    <XML_DECL tokenValue="<?xml" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="0">
      <TOKEN tokenValue="<?xml" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="0"/>
      <VERSION_INFO tokenValue="version" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="6">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="version" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="6"/>
        <EQ tokenValue="=" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="13">
          <TOKEN tokenValue="=" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="13"/>
        </EQ>
        <TOKEN tokenValue=""" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="14"/>
        <VERSION_NUM tokenValue="1." tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="15">
          <TOKEN tokenValue="1." tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="15"/>
          <TOKEN tokenValue="0" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="17"/>
        </VERSION_NUM>
        <TOKEN tokenValue=""" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="18"/>
      </VERSION_INFO>
      <ENCODING_DECL tokenValue="encoding" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="20">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="encoding" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="20"/>
        <EQ tokenValue="=" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="28">
          <TOKEN tokenValue="=" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="28"/>
        </EQ>
        <TOKEN tokenValue=""" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="29"/>
        <ENC_NAME tokenValue="UTF-8" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="30">
          <TOKEN tokenValue="UTF-8" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="30"/>
        </ENC_NAME>
        <TOKEN tokenValue=""" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="35"/>
      </ENCODING_DECL>
      <TOKEN tokenValue="?>" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="38"/>
    </XML_DECL>
    <MISC/>
  </PROLOG>
  <ELEMENT tokenValue="<" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="0">
    <S_TAG tokenValue="<" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="0">
      <TOKEN tokenValue="<" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="0"/>
      <NAME tokenValue="root" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="1">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="root" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="1"/>
      </NAME>
      <TOKEN tokenValue=">" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="5"/>
    </S_TAG>
    <CONTENT tokenValue="           

" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="6">
      <CHAR_DATA tokenValue="           

" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="6">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="         

" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="6"/>
      </CHAR_DATA>
    </CONTENT>
    <E_TAG tokenValue="</" tokenLine="5" tokenColumn="0">
      <TOKEN tokenValue="</" tokenLine="5" tokenColumn="0"/>
      <NAME tokenValue="root" tokenLine="5" tokenColumn="2">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="root" tokenLine="5" tokenColumn="2"/>
      </NAME>
      <TOKEN tokenValue=">" tokenLine="5" tokenColumn="6"/>
    </E_TAG>
  </ELEMENT>
  <MISC/>
</DOCUMENT>
```

And the log of the analysis :

```
Retrieve remote issues of project prjtest...
Start SonarQube analysis on prjtest...
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.3
09:26:29.309 INFO  - Preview mode
09:26:29.315 INFO  - Load batch settings
09:26:29.329 DEBUG - Download: http://xxxx/sonar/batch_bootstrap/properties?dryRun=true (no proxy)
09:26:29.554 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\xxxxx-s\.sonar\cache
09:26:29.567 INFO  - Install plugins
09:26:29.567 DEBUG - Download index of plugins
09:26:29.567 DEBUG - Download: http://xxxxxx/sonar/deploy/plugins/index.txt (no proxy)
09:26:29.598 INFO  - Include plugins: 
09:26:29.599 INFO  - Exclude plugins: devcockpit, buildstability, pdfreport, report, buildbreaker, scmactivity, views, jira
09:26:29.847 DEBUG - Download: http://xxxx/sonar/batch_bootstrap/db?project=fr.sihm.eand:prjtest (no proxy)
09:26:30.111 DEBUG - Dry Run database size: 1 MB
09:26:30.119 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:D:\java\workspaces\wks-luna-SR1-01-Sonar\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\prjtest\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\.sonartmp\preview1414743989840-0
09:26:30.845 DEBUG - Testing JDBC connection
09:26:32.049 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
09:26:32.053 DEBUG - hibernate.generate_statistics: false
09:26:32.053 DEBUG - hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
09:26:32.053 DEBUG - hibernate.connection.provider_class: org.sonar.jpa.session.CustomHibernateConnectionProvider
09:26:33.503 DEBUG - Loaded 3276 properties from l10n bundles
09:26:35.161 INFO  - Load project settings
09:26:35.161 DEBUG - Download: http://xxxxxx/sonar/batch_bootstrap/properties?project=fr.sihm.eand:prjtest&amp;dryRun=true (no proxy)
09:26:35.216 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
09:26:35.452 DEBUG - ooo Using Connection [jdbc:h2:D:\java\workspaces\wks-luna-SR1-01-Sonar\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\prjtest\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\.sonartmp\preview1414743989840-0, UserName=SONAR, H2 JDBC Driver]
09:26:35.457 DEBUG - ==>  Preparing: select * from projects p where p.id=? 
09:26:35.482 DEBUG - ==> Parameters: 14701(Long)
09:26:35.734 INFO  - -------------  Scan prjtest
09:26:35.763 INFO  - Load module settings
09:26:35.797 DEBUG - Download: http://xxxx/sonar/batch_bootstrap/properties?project=fr.sihm.eand:prjtest&amp;dryRun=true (no proxy)
09:26:36.162 DEBUG - Available languages:
09:26:36.163 DEBUG -   * Java => "java"
09:26:36.163 DEBUG -   * Web => "web"
09:26:36.163 DEBUG -   * XML => "xml"
09:26:36.163 DEBUG -   * JavaScript => "js"
09:26:37.142 INFO  - Loading technical debt model...
09:26:37.181 INFO  - Loading technical debt model done: 39 ms
09:26:37.204 INFO  - Loading rules...
09:26:37.711 INFO  - Loading rules done: 507 ms
09:26:37.780 INFO  - Configure Maven plugins
09:26:37.970 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2014-10-30)
09:26:37.991 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2014-10-01, analysis of 2014-10-23 15:42:10.95)
09:26:37.993 INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
09:26:38.340 DEBUG - Initializers : 
09:26:38.340 INFO  - Base dir: D:\001-Projets\Sonar\prjtest
09:26:38.340 INFO  - Working dir: D:\java\workspaces\wks-luna-SR1-01-Sonar\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\prjtest\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core
09:26:38.340 INFO  - Source dirs: D:\001-Projets\Sonar\prjtest\src
09:26:38.340 INFO  - Binary dirs: D:\001-Projets\Sonar\prjtest\bin
09:26:38.340 INFO  - Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: fr_FR
09:26:38.341 INFO  - Index files
09:26:38.346 DEBUG - Declared extensions of language Java were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.java : **/*.java,**/*.jav
09:26:38.346 DEBUG - Declared extensions of language Web were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.web : **/*.html,**/*.xhtml,**/*.jsp,**/*.jspf,**/*.jsf,**/*.php,**/*.erb,**/*.rhtml
09:26:38.346 DEBUG - Declared extensions of language XML were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.xml : **/*.xml
09:26:38.347 DEBUG - Declared extensions of language JavaScript were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.js : **/*.js
09:26:38.438 DEBUG - Language of file 'src/Jx_bad.xml' is detected to be 'xml'
09:26:38.542 DEBUG - Language of file 'src/Jx_G_J_Ds2MoJoDs_good.xml' is detected to be 'xml'
09:26:38.544 DEBUG - Language of file 'src/NewFile.xml' is detected to be 'xml'
09:26:38.545 INFO  - 3 files indexed
09:26:38.669 INFO  - Quality profile for xml: SIHM - DTS - Général
09:26:38.726 DEBUG - Sensors : QProfileSensor -> CpdSensor -> XmlSensor -> LineCountSensor -> JaCoCoSensor -> JaCoCoItSensor -> JaCoCoOverallSensor -> InitialOpenIssuesSensor -> ProfileEventsSensor -> ProjectLinksSensor
09:26:38.727 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor...
09:26:38.739 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor done: 12 ms
09:26:38.740 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor...
09:26:38.740 DEBUG - Detection of duplicated code is not supported for xml
09:26:38.740 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor done: 0 ms
09:26:38.740 INFO  - Sensor XmlSensor...
09:26:39.126 INFO  - Sensor XmlSensor done: 386 ms
09:26:39.127 INFO  - Sensor LineCountSensor...
09:26:39.137 DEBUG - Count comment in D:\001-Projets\Sonar\prjtest\src\Jx_G_J_Ds2MoJoDs_good.xml
09:26:39.167 DEBUG - LineCountSensor: src/Jx_G_J_Ds2MoJoDs_good.xml:920,17,0
09:26:39.168 DEBUG - Count comment in D:\001-Projets\Sonar\prjtest\src\Jx_bad.xml
09:26:39.172 DEBUG - LineCountSensor: src/Jx_bad.xml:10,0,0
09:26:39.174 DEBUG - Count comment in D:\001-Projets\Sonar\prjtest\src\NewFile.xml
09:26:39.177 DEBUG - LineCountSensor: src/NewFile.xml:5,2,0
09:26:39.177 INFO  - Sensor LineCountSensor done: 51 ms
09:26:39.177 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
09:26:39.188 INFO  - Project coverage is set to 0% as no JaCoCo execution data has been dumped: D:\001-Projets\Sonar\prjtest\target\jacoco.exec
09:26:39.205 WARN  - Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include debug information into compiled classes?
09:26:39.205 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 28 ms
09:26:39.206 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoItSensor...
09:26:39.208 INFO  - Project coverage is set to 0% as no JaCoCo execution data has been dumped: D:\001-Projets\Sonar\prjtest\target\jacoco-it.exec
09:26:39.209 WARN  - Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include debug information into compiled classes?
09:26:39.209 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoItSensor done: 3 ms
09:26:39.209 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor...
09:26:39.209 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor done: 0 ms
09:26:39.209 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
09:26:39.232 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 23 ms
09:26:39.233 INFO  - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
09:26:39.266 INFO  - Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 33 ms
09:26:39.266 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
09:26:39.285 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 19 ms
09:26:39.436 INFO  - Execute decorators...
09:26:39.437 DEBUG - Decorators: ManualMeasureDecorator -> org.sonar.issuesreport.tree.ResourceTree@480994d3 -> SumDuplicationsDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.ProjectDsmDecorator@7146c6ea -> FileTangleIndexDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.IssueTrackingDecorator@a5d23c9 -> UnitTestDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.DirectoriesDecorator@6065bcb7 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.FilesDecorator@1ee6434 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TimeMachineConfigurationPersister@59ec5a0b -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageAggregator@71d78cac -> org.sonar.plugins.uselesscodetracker.decorator.TempMethodLinesDecorator@550f522b -> org.sonar.plugins.uselesscodetracker.decorator.DuplicationsDecorator@6a7fc4c1 -> f(lines) -> f(generated_lines) -> f(ncloc) -> f(generated_ncloc) -> f(classes) -> f(packages) -> f(functions) -> f(accessors) -> f(statements) -> f(public_api) -> f(comment_lines) -> f(comment_blank_lines) -> f(public_undocumented_api) -> f(commented_out_code_lines) -> f(complexity) -> f(complexity_in_classes) -> f(complexity_in_functions) -> f(class_complexity_distribution) -> f(function_complexity_distribution) -> f(file_complexity_distribution) -> f(lines_to_cover) -> f(uncovered_lines) -> f(conditions_to_cover) -> f(uncovered_conditions) -> f(it_lines_to_cover) -> f(it_uncovered_lines) -> f(it_conditions_to_cover) -> f(it_uncovered_conditions) -> f(overall_lines_to_cover) -> f(overall_uncovered_lines) -> f(overall_conditions_to_cover) -> f(overall_uncovered_conditions) -> f(rfc) -> f(rfc_distribution) -> f(lcom4_distribution) -> f(package_cycles) -> f(package_tangles) -> f(package_feedback_edges) -> f(package_edges_weight) -> f(new_lines_to_cover) -> f(new_uncovered_lines) -> f(new_conditions_to_cover) -> f(new_uncovered_conditions) -> f(new_it_lines_to_cover) -> f(new_it_uncovered_lines) -> f(new_it_conditions_to_cover) -> f(new_it_uncovered_conditions) -> f(new_overall_lines_to_cover) -> f(new_overall_uncovered_lines) -> f(new_overall_conditions_to_cover) -> f(new_overall_uncovered_conditions) -> org.sonar.plugins.cpd.decorators.DuplicationDensityDecorator@2c7c898a -> PackageTangleIndexDecorator -> CountUnresolvedIssuesDecorator -> CountFalsePositivesDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.core.technicaldebt.DebtDecorator@23dc70c1 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.technicaldebt.NewDebtDecorator@53b907d9 -> CommentDensityDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.uselesscodetracker.decorator.TotalDecorator@1842dc39 -> f(file_complexity) -> f(class_complexity) -> f(function_complexity) -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.CoverageDecorator@6167c42f -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.LineCoverageDecorator@2cbc2db2 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.BranchCoverageDecorator@2de96eba -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItLineCoverageDecorator@6296e4bf -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItCoverageDecorator@220cda54 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItBranchCoverageDecorator@39109603 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallLineCoverageDecorator@4d3990a5 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallCoverageDecorator@18df26a1 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallBranchCoverageDecorator@5c459194 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.WeightedIssuesDecorator@fe38c0e -> ViolationDensityDecorator -> IssuesDensityDecorator -> VariationDecorator
09:26:39.617 DEBUG - Decorator time:
    ManualMeasureDecorator: 12ms
    org.sonar.issuesreport.tree.ResourceTree@480994d3: 1ms
    SumDuplicationsDecorator: 7ms
    org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.ProjectDsmDecorator@7146c6ea: 0ms
    FileTangleIndexDecorator: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.IssueTrackingDecorator@a5d23c9: 75ms
    UnitTestDecorator: 1ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.DirectoriesDecorator@6065bcb7: 1ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.FilesDecorator@1ee6434: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TimeMachineConfigurationPersister@59ec5a0b: 5ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageAggregator@71d78cac: 3ms
    org.sonar.plugins.uselesscodetracker.decorator.TempMethodLinesDecorator@550f522b: 10ms
    org.sonar.plugins.uselesscodetracker.decorator.DuplicationsDecorator@6a7fc4c1: 0ms
    f(lines): 0ms
    f(generated_lines): 0ms
    f(ncloc): 0ms
    f(generated_ncloc): 0ms
    f(classes): 0ms
    f(packages): 0ms
    f(functions): 0ms
    f(accessors): 0ms
    f(statements): 0ms
    f(public_api): 0ms
    f(comment_lines): 0ms
    f(comment_blank_lines): 0ms
    f(public_undocumented_api): 0ms
    f(commented_out_code_lines): 0ms
    f(complexity): 0ms
    f(complexity_in_classes): 1ms
    f(complexity_in_functions): 0ms
    f(class_complexity_distribution): 0ms
    f(function_complexity_distribution): 0ms
    f(file_complexity_distribution): 0ms
    f(lines_to_cover): 0ms
    f(uncovered_lines): 0ms
    f(conditions_to_cover): 0ms
    f(uncovered_conditions): 0ms
    f(it_lines_to_cover): 1ms
    f(it_uncovered_lines): 0ms
    f(it_conditions_to_cover): 1ms
    f(it_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
    f(overall_lines_to_cover): 0ms
    f(overall_uncovered_lines): 0ms
    f(overall_conditions_to_cover): 1ms
    f(overall_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
    f(rfc): 0ms
    f(rfc_distribution): 0ms
    f(lcom4_distribution): 0ms
    f(package_cycles): 0ms
    f(package_tangles): 0ms
    f(package_feedback_edges): 0ms
    f(package_edges_weight): 0ms
    f(new_lines_to_cover): 0ms
    f(new_uncovered_lines): 0ms
    f(new_conditions_to_cover): 0ms
    f(new_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
    f(new_it_lines_to_cover): 0ms
    f(new_it_uncovered_lines): 0ms
    f(new_it_conditions_to_cover): 0ms
    f(new_it_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
    f(new_overall_lines_to_cover): 0ms
    f(new_overall_uncovered_lines): 0ms
    f(new_overall_conditions_to_cover): 0ms
    f(new_overall_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.cpd.decorators.DuplicationDensityDecorator@2c7c898a: 1ms
    PackageTangleIndexDecorator: 0ms
    CountUnresolvedIssuesDecorator: 14ms
    CountFalsePositivesDecorator: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.technicaldebt.DebtDecorator@23dc70c1: 5ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.technicaldebt.NewDebtDecorator@53b907d9: 2ms
    CommentDensityDecorator: 4ms
    org.sonar.plugins.uselesscodetracker.decorator.TotalDecorator@1842dc39: 0ms
    f(file_complexity): 0ms
    f(class_complexity): 0ms
    f(function_complexity): 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.CoverageDecorator@6167c42f: 1ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.LineCoverageDecorator@2cbc2db2: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.BranchCoverageDecorator@2de96eba: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItLineCoverageDecorator@6296e4bf: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItCoverageDecorator@220cda54: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItBranchCoverageDecorator@39109603: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallLineCoverageDecorator@4d3990a5: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallCoverageDecorator@18df26a1: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallBranchCoverageDecorator@5c459194: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.WeightedIssuesDecorator@fe38c0e: 4ms
    ViolationDensityDecorator: 1ms
    IssuesDensityDecorator: 0ms
    VariationDecorator: 25ms

09:26:39.619 DEBUG - 162 measures to dump
09:26:39.706 INFO  - Export results to D:\java\workspaces\wks-luna-SR1-01-Sonar\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\prjtest\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\sonar-report.json
09:26:39.712 INFO  - Store results in database
09:26:39.713 DEBUG - Execute org.sonar.batch.index.ComponentDataPersister
09:26:39.719 DEBUG - Execute org.sonar.batch.issue.IssuePersister
09:26:39.719 DEBUG - IssuePersister skipped in preview mode
09:26:39.719 DEBUG - Execute org.sonar.batch.phases.GraphPersister
09:26:39.804 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
09:26:39.807 DEBUG - Post-jobs : org.sonar.issuesreport.ReportJob@276aa33f
09:26:39.807 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.issuesreport.ReportJob
09:26:39.813 DEBUG - Generating HTML Report to: D:\java\workspaces\wks-luna-SR1-01-Sonar\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\prjtest\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\issues-report\issues-report.html
09:26:40.176 INFO  - HTML Issues Report generated: D:\java\workspaces\wks-luna-SR1-01-Sonar\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\prjtest\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\issues-report\issues-report.html
09:26:40.176 DEBUG - Generating Light HTML Report to: D:\java\workspaces\wks-luna-SR1-01-Sonar\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\prjtest\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\issues-report\issues-report-light.html
09:26:40.212 INFO  - Light HTML Issues Report generated: D:\java\workspaces\wks-luna-SR1-01-Sonar\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\prjtest\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\issues-report\issues-report-light.html
09:26:40.236 INFO  - 

-------------  Issues Report  -------------

  No new issue

-------------------------------------------
```

I am very confused. Can anybody help me ?

Comment: After creation of the custom rule, did you activate it on your quality profile?

Comment: Yes of course, in the log : INFO  - Quality profile for xml: SIHM - DTS - Général (the sonar rules work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution : custom xpath rules for the xml plugin works on the XML file directly and not on the AST tree ... (unlike the Java Plugin ;))

In my example the xpath rule must be :
`/root`